# How can I save an xml containing multiple xml:base attributes to multiple files

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I have an xml file similar to:

```
<main xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <level1 xml:base="./include1/include1.xml">
    <level2 xml:base="./include1/include2/include2.xml">
      <level3 xml:base="./include2/include3/include3.xml">
        <level4 xml:base="./include3/include4/include4.xml">
          <data>0</data>
          <data>1</data>
        </level4>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
</main>
```

The file was generated by assembling multiple xml files through the use of xi:include.
In particular, the file in the example is generated by the following files:

**./main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<main  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="./include1/include1.xml" />
</main >
```

**./include1/include1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<level1  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="./include2/include2.xml" />
</level1 >
```

**./include1/include2/include2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<level2  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="./include3/include3.xml" />
</level2 >
```

**./include1/include2/include3/include3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<level3  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="./include4/include4.xml" />
</level3 >
```

**./include1/include2/include3/include4/include4.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<level4  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <data> 0 </data>
    <data> 1 </data>
</level4 >
```

Now, after doing some processing on the data in the output file, I would like to save back the original files, retrieving the original folder tree structure.

I tried to write my own XQuery script to accomplish this goal, by recurring inside the output file, processing the values stored in the **xml:base** attributes and saving the files.

However, now, after writing more than 150 lines of beginner-level XQuery code, I feel lost.

I'm thus wondering if someone has already developed some XQuery or XSLT code that implements this functionality (I think that overall it should be a pretty common functionality...) or if I can use some existing library to perform this task.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it fairly easily in XSLT with something like

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy">
  <xsl:template match="*[@xml:base]">
    <xi:include href="{@xml:base}"/>
    <xsl:result-document href="{@xml:base}">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @xml:base"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I don't see how you could do it in XQuery which lacks any equivalent of `xsl:result-document`.

The only difficulty is getting the value of the `href` attribute correct on both the `xsl:result-document` and the `xi:include` elements. The way I've written it, the relative URI in the `@xml:base` attribute will be resolved against the base output URI of the transformation. You might get better results using the value of `base-uri(.)` which resolves it against ancestor base URIs, but the problem is that is then likely to be an absolute URI in the same directory as the source document. Perhaps use `base-uri(.)` with some prefix-stripping to make it relative, or perhaps use an `OutputURIResolver` to redirect the final output location.